# Android BroadcastReceiver not receiving BOOT_COMPLETED event

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I have created in my application a **BroadcastReceiver** that receives the 
BOOT_COMPLETED event (`BootReceiver`) and then start a service (`NtService`) this service have a public static boolean (`started`) that is setted to true by his `onCreate()` method but when i print the var to the console in the MainActivity the boolean is still false.

The application is installed in **Internal Storage**,and i'm debugging it in the android studio emulator by submitting this command on adb shell:

```
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Here is the code:

**BootReceiver**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, NtService.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**NtService**

```
   import android.app.Service;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.IBinder;

   public class NtService extends Service {
     public static boolean started;

     public NtService() {
     }

     @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
         return null;
     }

     public void onCreate(){
         started=true;
     }
   }
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.primerdime.cloudchat">
    <!-- PERMISSION -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:installLocation="internalOnly"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".registration" />
            <!-- SERVICE AND RECEIVER -->
            <service
                android:name=".NtService"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="false" />

            <receiver
                android:name=".BootReceiver"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="false">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action._BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `android:exported="false"` from the `<receiver>` element. As it stands, it cannot receive broadcasts from outside of the app.

Also, you have a typo in the `<action>` element. It should be `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />`.

And, finally, replace `context.startActivity(i);` with `context.startService(i);`, as you are trying to start a service, not an activity.

Comment: I've removed `android:exported="false"` and corrected typo in `<action>` but is still not working